# How to set a default value for a field in graphene

Tags: python, graphene-python

I am experimenting with graphene in setting

1.) A default value for a field (just like how defaultdict works in python)

Ex :-

```
Class something(graphene.ObjectType):
    FieldA = graphene.Float() or return a defaultValue
```

2.) Set a field of multiple type

Ex:-

```
Class something(graphene.ObjectType):
    FieldA = graphene.Float() or graphene.String() or None
```

I am new to graphene & I am going through the documentation.

Any help/pointer is appreciated in getting the above 2 done.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. For default values...

The docs don't do a great job of showing examples but the info you need is here: https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/scalars/

> All Scalar types accept the following arguments. All are optional:
>
> - `name`: string
>   Override the name of the Field.
> - `description`: string
>   A description of the type to show in the GraphiQL browser.
> - `required`: boolean
>   If `True`, the server will enforce a value for this field. See `NonNull`.
>   Default is `False`.
> - `deprecation_reason`: string
>   Provide a deprecation reason for the Field.
> - `default_value`: any
>   Provide a default value for the Field.

i.e. you can do:

```py
class Something(graphene.ObjectType):
    field_a = graphene.Float(default_value=1.23)
```

(note the capitalization: `class` keyword **must** be lowercase in Python, while `Something` class name, by convention, should be "camel case" i.e. first letter of each word capitalized, also by convention the `field_a` attribute should be "snake case" i.e. all lower-case with underscores as word separator)

#### 2. For field of multiple types...

The info you need is here: https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/unions/

i.e. you can do:

```py
class StringOrFloat(graphene.Union):
    class Meta:
        types = (graphene.String, graphene.Float)

class Something(graphene.ObjectType):
    field_a = StringOrFloat()
```

Comment: is there any way that the default_value can be a None, for ex :- field_a = graphene.Float(default_value="SomeString/Invalid")

Comment: I think that's basically what `required=False` means (which is the default behaviour of fields)

Comment: try it and see!

Comment: i dont think required=False  was right, it did not work

Comment: it should be something like to be able to able None/string as the output. Thanks for help :)

Comment: you might be able to `default_value=None` ?

Comment: is there any way by which we can have something like                     
 types = (graphene.String, graphene.None) or types = (graphene.String, None) as per the 2nd example, default_value=None did not work

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that. I think it's probably worth exploring as a separate question, with an example of the code that doesn't behave the way you want it to

Comment: thanks for all the help, i was  not able to handle NaN in graphql hence wanted to try these methods

Comment: `NaN` is not the same as `None`... I'm not sure how well a graphene.Float field handles it but NaN is a float value and can be serialized to/from string in Python e.g. `str(float("NaN")) == 'nan'`